# how to Monitor database replication in veeam enterprise manager through restful api

Tags: veeam

i am unable to find any solution to monitor the database replication in session in veeam enterprise manager.

the problem i am working on this use case: [Monitor database replication](https://forums.veeam.com/restful-api-f30/monitor-database-replication-t44404.html)
since no solution is here and it is old issue.

so is there an API that let me see the status of database replication in veeam  enterprise manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veeam doesn't provide the direct restful api to monitor these replication.

Here is [Veeam response](https://forums.veeam.com/restful-api-f30/monitor-database-replication-t44404.html)